# No CPU option in cycles compute device

Tags: rendering

With the 2.79b version i want to enable both CPU and GPU for render. But i can only find the GPU settings.

[image]

Under the CUDA i can seen my GPU card and not my system setting

May i know where is the setting for Both GPU and CPU to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're referring to hasn't made it into Blender 2.79b. If I recall correctly, it was finished after the release of 2.79b. If you still want to give it a shot, you can go to the Buildbot page at https://builder.blender.org/download/ and download the **Official** build from there.

Once you start that one up, the User Preferences will show you these checkboxes when you enable CUDA:

[image: Buildbot Official]

As you can see, my CPU is listed as `Intel Xeon CPU E5-2640`, and can be used in addition to the TitanX.

On the same computer, Blender 2.79b doesn't show the additional CPU option:

[image: 2.79 b]

Answer (score 0):

The CPU don't need to be enabled in the user preferences. It's in the Properties window, at the right side at the 3D View in render Tab. There you can decide if GPU or CPU. In 2.8 it could be possible to use both at the same time. [image]